# Multiple file and images not uploading in laravel without loop

Tags: laravel, file-upload

I face a problem in laravel that is i'm trying to upload image and other files like pdf, word files but laravel give me a error named as "***Symfony \ Component \ HttpFoundation \ File \ Exception \ FileException
The file "banner.PNG" was not uploaded due to an unknown error***". I tried many times to solve this issue with different way but not success.

Please help me out. thanks

Error is
**The file "banner.PNG" was not uploaded due to an unknown error**

My code here

```
       if ($file = $request->file('user_img'))
        {
            $name = time().$file->getClientOriginalName();
            
            $file->move('files/instructor/', $name);
            $input['user_img'] = $name;
        }

        if ($file1 = $request->file('cnic'))
        {
            $name1 = time().$file1->getClientOriginalName();
            
            $file1->move(public_path().'files/instructor_cnic/', $name1);
            $input['cnic'] = $name1;
        }
      
        


        if($file = $request->file('resume'))
        {
            $name = time().$file->getClientOriginalName();
            $file->move('files/instructor_resume/',$name);
            $input['resume'] = $name;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

try with this....

```
if ($request->hasFile('user_img'))
    {
        $file = $request-> user_img;
        $name = time().$file->getClientOriginalName();
        
        $file->move('files/instructor/', $name);
        $input['user_img'] = $name;
    }

    if ($request->hasFile('cnic'))
    {
        $file1 = $request-> cnic;
        $name1 = time().$file1->getClientOriginalName();
        
        $file1->move(public_path().'files/instructor_cnic/', $name1);
        $input['cnic'] = $name1;
    }
  
    


    if($request->hasFile('resume'))
    {
        $file2 = $request-> resume;
        $name = time().$file->getClientOriginalName();
        $file2->move('files/instructor_resume/',$name);
        $input['resume'] = $name;
    }
```

Comment: this solution is not work. i already apply this type of solution. please give me perfect solution. thanks.